# issues printing bar code in a Zebra ZXP series 3 printer

Tags: .net, printing, barcode, zebra-printers

I'm using the ZEBRA SDK to print into PVC cards, the text prints good, the imgages are good too, but when i try to print bar codes they show up as text (raw cpcl maybe?), and I have tried many thinks:

-reinstalled drivers (usb).
-print over usb 2.0.
-print with the 64bit SDK.
-print with the 32bit SDK.
-factory defaulted the printer settings.
-updated the printer firmware to lasted version from the zebra website.

the tutorial i'm following is the next one:

[[zebra tutorial from ZXP 3](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/software-printer/dt/card-sdk/getting-started-zxp3-sdk-c-sharp.pdf)][1](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/software-printer/dt/card-sdk/getting-started-zxp3-sdk-c-sharp.pdf)

picture of my issue:

[image]

-here is my code:

```
                if (graphics.DrawBarcode(10, 10, 0, 0, 2, 3, 30, 1, ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CodigoCliente.Trim().ToCharArray()), out errValue) == 0)
                {
                    msg = "Printing DrawBarcode Error: " + errValue.ToString();
                    TBLog.Text += Environment.NewLine + msg;
                    return;
                }
```

-what should I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed the guide provided on the link above "zebra tutorial from ZXP 3]1", it looks that you only downloaded the sample code from GitHub, but you didn't download the dlls files needed to work with the code.

The ZXP3 printer is already discontinued, the replacement printer is the [ZC300 card printer](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/printers/card/zc300-series.html)

For the ZXP3 printer you would be able to download the dlls and the SDK from the link below. Once you have downloaded the zip file, and extracted it in your pc, you would be able to access a full sample code, the PDF manual, the dlls.

[ZXP3 DLLS/SDK](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/forms/card/zxps3-downloads.html)

Be aware that there are two dll libraries. One called ZBRPrinter.dll that manages all related to communication interface of the printer. The other library is ZBRGraphics.dll. This second library is the one you need to use for the barcode.

However, if the barcode is not working properly with your application. You don't need to work with that ZBRGraphics, you could use any other C# libraries in the market that allow you to build the barcode, then you can insert the graphic in your print job, like per example the one found on GitHub on the link below.

https://github.com/ScoreBig/barcoderender

MC

Comment: I ended up using your last solution, i used Zxing.net (https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net) to generate de barcode  and print it as an  image on the card, there was some driver issue with SDK code bar command.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to print a barcode on any of the card printers, several issues could prevent a barcode printout. Most of these settings need to be checked or made on the application being used to design the barcode. These settings may include:

1. **The barcode parameters are invalid.** *Each barcode type has a specific set of legal parameters, including the length, width ratios, and acceptable characters. Consult the barcode section at the end of the EPCL or SDK manual to see exact specifications.*
2. **The barcode does not fit in the printing area.** *If any part of the barcode falls outside of the printable area, it will not print at all. Make sure you are within card limits.*
3. **The printer is not set to print the black (K) ribbon panel on the card side with the barcode.** *In the driver's Printing Preferences, for printers using color-ribbon, there is a property to choose which panels are printed to each side of the card.  Barcodes are generally printed with the black (K) panel. Ensure that the black (K) panel is set to print on the side of the card holding the barcode.*

For more help, visit this reference link:

[ZXP7 CARD PRINTER BARCODES FAIL TO SCAN DUE TO K PANEL MONOCHROME SETTINGS](https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/ZXP7-Card-Printer-Barcodes-fail-to-scan-due-to-K-Panel-Monochrome-Settings?language=en_US)

**ISSUE / QUESTION**

- Barcode fails to scan due to driver settings for the K Panel
- Bar Codes do not read
- The scanner is not able to read the printed barcode on the cards.

Example:

[image: On the Front selection choose Barcode followed by Apply and Ok.]

Best luck!

Comment: this was useful to solve some font relatedd issues but it did not solve the codebar's issues, but helpful anyway. +1